# What is $f(\phi)$ evaluated for the first $n$ terms?

Tags: linear-algebra, functions, asymptotics

### Background

I have been recently toying with the following function:

$$ f(x) = x - x^2 + x^4 - x^8 + x^{16} - \dots = \sum_{r=0}^\infty (-1)^{r}x^{2^r}$$

My idea was to expand around $x \to \phi$ where $\phi + \phi^2 = 1$ and evaluate the answer for the first $n$ terms.

It's obvious the answer must be of the form:

$$ f(\phi) = \lim_{n \to \infty}(a_1(n) + a_2(n) \phi)$$

where $a_1(n)$ and $a_2(n)$ is the sum of the first $n$ terms in the simplified to the form: $$\sum_{r=0}^n (-1)^{r}\phi^{2^r} = \underbrace{\text{Integer}_1}_{a_1(n)} + \underbrace{\text{Integer}_2}_{a_2(n)} \phi $$

### Question

Is there any nice asymptotic or exact expression a for $a_1(n)$ and $a_2(n)$?

Comment: Do you mean
$$
\sum_{r=0}^{\infty} (-1)^{r} x^{2^r}
$$ ?

Comment: Yes sorry will edit ... Done!

Comment: Why do you need separate symbols $a_1$ and $a_2$ if they are the same?

Comment: $a_2$ is multiplied by $\phi$ ... And one should be able to evaluate the answer in form for the first $n$ terms as: $a_1(n) + a_2(n) \phi$. For example, consider evaluating the upto $2$ terms .. $\phi - \phi^2 = 2\phi -1$. Now, $ a_1(2) = -1 $  and $a_2(2) = 2$

Comment: @MoreAnonymous Then the description "$a_1(n)$ and $a_2(n)$ is the sum of the first $n$ terms" is misleading.

Comment: @YiFan is this better? (If not feel free to edit till it becomes clearer)